# Flickr style thumbnail page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How is [Flickr Explore](http://www.flickr.com/explore) thumbnail grid page done? Is this possible using bootstrap and still retain the responsiveness of the images? I checked the Flickr page and it seems that those images are set as background-image.

Is there any similar CSS technique to copy that effect?

Comment: almost everything is possible if you provide code...

Comment: Have a look at jQuery Masonry.

Comment: I dont need to provide code on this one. The code im trying to replicate is there on that flickr page and Im just asking for a bootstrap implementation of it.

Comment: Bram's recommendation solved my problem. Masonry work's well with Bootstrap.